# Calculate the sum from different tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

My **receipt** table

```
Partnumber | Receipt | Location
```

And an **sales** table:

```
Partnumber | Sales | Location
```

What im trying to do is to calculate the stock quantity per location and per part number. I have the query to do this for one table:

Here i calculate the receipt parts on that location per partnumber

```
SELECT Location, sum(Receipt) FROM receipt WHERE Partnumber = 100 GROUP BY Location
```

You need to do the same with the sales table. And on the end i want to calculate the sum from the receipt table per location - the sum from the sales table per location.

**Data:**

```
Partnumber | Receipt | Location

100          2         500
100          5         500
100          2         300
200          4         600
300          8         500


Partnumber | Sales | Location

100          1         500
300          4         500
100          1         300
```

And here is the output:

```
Partnumber | stock |  location
100          6        500
100          1        300
200          4        600
300          4        500
```

So count the receipt articles based on part number per location minus the count sales on part number per location. Is this possible with one query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know how to calculate the total number of parts received:

```
SELECT Location, SUM(Receipt)
FROM receipt WHERE Partnumber = 100 GROUP BY Location ;
```

Calculating the total number of parts sold is similar:

```
SELECT Location, SUM(Sales)
FROM sales WHERE Partnumber = 100 GROUP BY Location ;
```

Now all you need is calculate the difference, and all it takes is combining the two above queries:

```
SELECT Location, (receipt_count - COALESCE(sales_count, 0)) AS current_stock
FROM (
    SELECT Location, SUM(Receipt) AS receipt_count
    FROM receipt WHERE Partnumber = 100 GROUP BY Location
) AS Receipt
LEFT JOIN
 (
    SELECT Location, SUM(Sales) AS sales_count
    FROM sales WHERE Partnumber = 100 GROUP BY Location
) AS Sales USING (Location)
```

Comment: It works! But the query is outputting one line.. how can i fix this? Because an Partnumber can have more than 1 location. I have edited my output.

Comment: Oh yes, this can happen if a Part Number was never sold in some location. The `[INNER] JOIN` will filter out such locations. Replace with `LEFT JOIN` and let me know how it looks now.

Comment: It shows now the locations.  only the calculation is not right, if you have an location in the receipt table and the same location in the sales table there is nothing wrong. But if you have a location in the receipt table that not excist in the sales table, than you get the output NULL.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that, see my edit, add a [`COALESCE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce)

Answer (score 0):

Union can be handy with this problem:

```
(SELECT Partnumber, Receipt as quantity, Location FROM receipt)
UNION
(SELECT Partnumber, (-Sales) as quantity, Location FROM sales)
```

this will return

```
PARTNUMBER | QUANTITY | LOCATION
    100    |       2  | 500
    100    |       5  | 500
    200    |       4  | 600
    300    |       8  | 500
    100    |      -1  | 500
    300    |      -4  | 500
```

Notice, how I put negative value for quantity from sales table.

Now with this, you can do what you need:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Partnumber, sum(quantity) as Stock, Location FROM
(
    (SELECT Partnumber, Receipt as quantity, Location FROM receipt)
    UNION
    (SELECT Partnumber, (-Sales) as quantity, Location FROM sales)
) as UnitedTable
GROUP BY Partnumber, Location;
```

Dont forget to group by Location AND Partnumber.
Result:

```
PARTNUMBER | STOCK | LOCATION
      100  |    6  | 500
      200  |    4  | 600
      300  |    4  | 500
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/76193d/19